# CMAKE RPATH problem for shared library dependency

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm building 2 targets in my CMake project: libA.so , and libB.so. B depends on A (B->A).

Declaration of target **A**:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")
add_library(A SHARED ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(A PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/> 
                                                    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:src/>)
#
# Installation
set(PACKAGE_NAME A)
set(PACKAGE_VERSION 1.0)

install(TARGETS ${PACKAGE_NAME} EXPORT ${PACKAGE_NAME}Targets
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/${PACKAGE_NAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/${PACKAGE_NAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include/${PACKAGE_NAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}
export(EXPORT ${PACKAGE_NAME}Targets
  FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}-${PACKAGE_VERSION}/${PACKAGE_NAME}Targets.cmake"
)
```

Declaration of target **B**:

```
add_library(B SHARED b.cpp)
target_include_directories(B PRIVATE 
                                $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}> 
                                $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:> )
target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC A)
#
# Installation
install(TARGETS B LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/B-1.0)
```

Now this works well in the code base, B has the right path to A:

> ldd  /home/user/dev/source_code/lib/libB.so

```
...
libA.so.1.0 => /home/user/dev/source_code/lib/libA.so.1.0 (0x0000007f7fe40000)
...
```

Now doing an installation to the system:

> sudo make install

they install to:

```
/usr/local/lib/A-1.0/libA.so.1.0
/usr/local/lib/B-1.0/libB.so
```

Now testing again

> ldd /usr/local/lib/B-1.0/libB.so

```
...
libA.so.1.0 => not found
...
```

So it would appear that RPATH is not being set correctly for **B** upon installation? Why isn't CMake figuring out the correct path to known target **A**?

Comment: Why `RPATH` would be set all of it sudden? It would break first variant.